# Respond CSS Not Working Properly

Tags: html, css, iframe, media

I am using https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond to help with my browser compatibility for responsive media queries but it doesn't seem to be working properly for I.E.

I have the respond.src.js file in the same folder as index.html / style.css.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="respond.src.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any ideas if I am doing anything wrong here?

I am then simply just adding an iFrame.

```
<body>

    <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/cR5BORA8Ij/embed/" width="300" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="myFrame"></iframe>  

</body>
```

The iFrame doesn't seem to load in IE 8.

Comment: are you sure you have the `respond.src.js` in your project, or do you have `respond.min.js`

Comment: Yes I have that file. Could it be the fact that I am using an iFrame too?

Comment: Can you show your code in its entirety ? (pertaining to this)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

It quotes:

**Reportedly, if CSS files are encoded in UTF-8 with Byte-Order-Mark (BOM), they will not work with Respond.js in IE7 or IE8. Noted in issue #97**

Comment: Try if you can use ASCII, or ISO-8859-1

Comment: What do you mean? I think it's my iFrame issue.

Comment: Try using "style" attribute instead of width:

 `<iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/cR5BORA8Ij/embed/" style="width:300; height:400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="myFrame"></iframe>`